# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

I made a web application from localhost and now im planning to put it online but after uploading my web application i got error in my console that says: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.

My ajax scripts are notwrking.

I cant even register and login in my web application now. How to fix this?

Comment: did you read the error message? it probably mentions something about a same-origin policy.

Comment: Simply, it means that you are trying to do cross-domain requests; obviously without configuring things on your server or client, depending on what the script should do. Update your question with some more information and maybe we could help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go inside your `.htaccess` file in your server's root and add this line to allow cross-domain requests:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

If no `.htaccess` file exists on your server then just create it.

Comment: how to create . htaccess?

Comment: Just open your Notepad on your pc, write the line I said in my answer inside of it and then save naming it ".htaccess" (quotes included).

Comment: where should i put the htaccess?

Comment: You have to put it in the root folder of your server (the "/" folder) so it will be "/.htaccess".

Comment: If you are trying to access another domain obviously it will not let you in if it hasn't setted the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. If you can't manage that domain there is not much to do...

Comment: its my domain...how come??? im confuse

Comment: You did something wrong. Make sure that your .htaccess file is in the root and that it has the right name, which is ".htaccess" without the quotes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with hostinger so I can't help you more than this.. sorry :/